# On Abhyankar's results cited in a paper of Manin titled "Correspondences, Motifs and Monoidal Transformations"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, motives

Consider the following from this paper "Correspondences, Motifs and Monoidal Transformations" of Manin [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1968v006n04ABEH001070/pdf).

> **Theorem.** *Nonsingular three-dimensional projective unirational varieties $V$ over a finite field satisfy the Riemann-Weil hypothesis.*
>
> **Sketch of the Proof.** We consider a rational map $f: \mathbb{P}^3 \to V$ of finite degree. By virtue of Abhyankar's results there exists a commutative diagram of the form
>
> [image]
>
> in which $g$ is a birational morphism which splits into a sequence of monoidal transformations with nonsingular centers, and $h$ is a morphism of finite degree (at a generic point).

**Question.** What are Abhyankar's results here, and could anybody give a sketch of a proof of them?

Comment: Presumably resolution for 3-folds...

Comment: Daniel is correct. It is far too long for anyone to sketch the proof here, but take a look at Lipman's "Introduction to resolution of singularities", in the Arcata proceedings for an exposition of some of the ideas.